# Geneland installation on R (Mac)

Tags: r, gcc, std

I am trying to install Geneland (from https://i-pri.org/special/Biostatistics/Software/Geneland/#Installation) on R version 3.5.1 on my Mac (Mojave 10.14.6).

I first add gcc issue, but followed this (https://nistara.net/post/compile-issues-r/) which did the trick and the installation could go further (gcc 9.2.0 installed via Brew).

However I am now stuck here:

```
> install.packages("~/Desktop/Geneland_4.0.8.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
* installing *source* package ‘Geneland’ ...
** libs
gfortran   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c alarousset.f -o alarousset.o
gfortran   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c ggfstat.f -o ggfstat.o
gfortran   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c hz.f -o hz.o
gfortran   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c main.f -o main.o
gcc-9 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -mtune=native -g -O2 -Wall -pedantic -Wconversion -c wrapper.c -o wrapper.o
In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h:61,
                 from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/R.h:55,
                 from wrapper.c:1:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/Availability.h:257:22: error: missing binary operator before token "("
  257 |     #if __has_builtin(__is_target_arch)
      |                      ^
make: *** [wrapper.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Geneland’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/Geneland’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘/Users/simon/Desktop/Geneland_4.0.8.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Would you have any idea how to solve this?
Thanks a lot in advance!

**EDIT**:
I was able to install Geneland by keeping **only** this line in the ~/.R/Makevars file:

```
FLIBS=-L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.2.0/lib/gcc/9
```

I hope this will help others!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully install on Windows (R v3.5). However, I'm having similar issues installing on Mac:

```
install.packages("~/Desktop/Geneland_4.0.8.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
* installing *source* package ‘Geneland’ ...
** using staged installation
** libs
gfortran  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c alarousset.f -o alarousset.o
gfortran-4.2: error trying to exec '/usr/local/bin/i686-apple-darwin8-gfortran-4.2': execvp: Bad CPU type in executable
make: *** [alarousset.o] Error 255
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Geneland’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/Geneland’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘/Users/jas/Desktop/Geneland_4.0.8.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Perhaps the creators of this package never tested on Mac or it was not designed to run on Mac (hopefully I'm wrong).

Also regarding gcc, I believe I have the latest version as per:

```
Jass-MacBook-Air:~ $ brew info gcc
gcc: stable 9.2.0 (bottled), HEAD
GNU compiler collection
https://gcc.gnu.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.2.0 (1,462 files, 291.4MB)
  Poured from bottle on 2019-09-17 at 11:08:00
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/gcc.rb
==> Dependencies
Required: gmp ✔, isl ✔, libmpc ✔, mpfr ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Analytics
install: 83,384 (30 days), 202,842 (90 days), 915,671 (365 days)
install_on_request: 37,664 (30 days), 91,399 (90 days), 435,332 (365 days)
build_error: 0 (30 days)
```

Comment: I edited my post: I was able to install Geneland successfully. Maybe my way around would be helpful for you as well.